# Supabase session empty when Signing In with Github

Tags: next.js, supabase

I have a method which checks if a session exists on a server, and if not, it should redirect to the sign-in page.

However, when I sign in with GitHub OAuth, the session is initially null on redirect, causing a final redirect to the sign-in page because the app thinks the user is not authenticated.

I could fix this with Client-Side check with useSessionContext, but I would prefer to keep it on the server side

I'm using NextJS 13 with pages router

Here is how my getServerSideProps method looks like:

```js
export const getServerSideProps: GetServerSideProps = async (ctx) => {
  const supabase = createServerSupabaseClient(ctx);
    const {
      data: { session },
    } = await supabase.auth.getSession();

  if (!session) {
    return {
      redirect: {
        destination: "/auth/sign-in",
        permanent: false,
      },
    };
  }

  return {
    props: {},
  };
};
```

Does anyone of you know what could fix this?

Comment: You can use the PKCE flow to complete the authentication on the server side. https://supabase.com/docs/guides/auth/server-side-rendering